# how to determine s3 browser upload policy expiration duration

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

I have moved server based s3 upload to direct upload to s3 from browser, I am setting policy on upload with some expiration.

```
$policy = array(
            'expiration' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', strtotime('+10 minutes')),
            'conditions' => array(
                    array('bucket' => Configure::Read('s3upload.s3bucket')),
                    array('acl' => 'private'),
                    array('starts-with', '$key', ''),
                    array('success_action_redirect' => $success_action_redirect),
                    array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''),
                    array("content-length-range", 0, 16*1024*1024) //16 mb
            )
    );
```

I need to pass AWSAccessKey, encoded policy, signature in form data, which can be compromise for fake uploads ( I have doubts on this as well).

To avoid exploitation i should be putting minimum expiration time ? but as client side, file size and connection speed can not be determined.

I have experimented with 10 seconds expiry and big file upload to verify, I observed all uploads attempts getting Policy expiration error,

> `<Error>
>         <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
>         <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.</Message>
>         <RequestId>2178D49CAA739EB3</RequestId>
>        <HostId>id=</HostId>
>     </Error>`

but as my WI-FI connection frequently disconnects so I am not able to determine correct behaviour, but with stable lan connection I am able to upload big file with smaller policy expiration.

How should I determine correct expiration value for policy expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.

```
array('starts-with', '$key', ''),
```

This allows *any* file in the bucket to be overwritten by manipulating the form.  Put the exact key where the file will be uploaded in the policy.  The worst anyone could do if they came into possession of the signature would then be to overwrite the same file.

However, if your site uses SSL and the S3 form post uses SSL, the chance of this information being compromised is very remote.

Note also that if form posts behave like signed GET requests, then the expiration duration *should* only matter until the upload starts.  Once it is running, it should be able to finish after the expiration without causing an error, as long as it starts before the expiration.  I assume that S3 authenticates the request when the headers are received, but perhaps that isn't true of form post uploads?  Are you finding that not to be the case?

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing out, I believe form post authentication behaves same, as I am able to upload big file with 10 sec expiration set.